# iphone send call log to google calendar (or my own server)

Tags: ios, iphone

I have been using IFTTT on Android to log calls on google calendar for business purposes (building a list for the boss).
Now I need this for iOS (iphone) also.

does anyone know a way to use an existing app to push call log data to a server?
just from_no, date, length

there's no legal/privacy issue here, these are company-issued phones and phone owners are happy to have this done.
Thank you for any suggestion

Comment: You will need to jailbreak the devices and/or use private frameworks and distribute via an enterprise program or direct install to do this.  There certainly won't be an an app in the App Store that can do this

Comment: that's a shame. any other work-around (something that does not involve jailbreaking and custom iOS programming).
For instance, manually backup the call log and email it to a special email (assuming it's not encrypted?)

Comment: Not that I know of.  In theory you could write a program to go through the iPhone backup file and look for the call log

Answer (score 0):

At present (iOS 7) this is not possible on a non-jailbroken iOS device

Comment: this is very sad, I don't understand why.
there must be other people looking for this kind of integration with CRMs, sales people, for instance.